# Strange result when dropping table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-drop

When I drop the table in `SQL` I get a strange result. My table was not dropped but shows:

> BIN$0X1RWoaWQlSLcefLZbH5jA==$0 TABLE

What is this?
How can I delete the table?

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. You might want to say which SQL software and system you are using, and show your SQL commands, otherwise it might be difficult to answer. Add the necessary details using the [edit] button.

Answer (score 1):

Since Oracle 10g the database has a [recycle bin](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/tables.htm#i1011340) containing the information of dropped tables. When you drop a table it's not really dropped, just registered in the recycle bin (instead of as a "regular" table) with a `BIN$` prefix and an auto-generated hash.

Once you're sure you application works properly and you really don't need this table anymore, you can get rid of it completely by using the [`purge`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9018.htm) command:

```
PURGE TABLE BIN$0X1RWoaWQlSLcefLZbH5jA==$0
```

Comment: If you don't want to type that table name (which you need to enclose in double quotes because of the lower case characters) you can also simply use `purge recyclebin`